# ng-hide depending on value of var

Tags: angularjs

In AngularJS, how can I do what the following code is trying to achieve, i.e. hide a span if task.status is set to a specific value?

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks">

    Move to:
    <span ng-hide="task.status=todo">Todo</span>
    <span ng-hide="task.status=doing">Doing</span>
    <span ng-hide="task.status=done">Done</span>

</li>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    Move to:
    <span ng-hide="task.status == todo">Todo</span>
    <span ng-hide="task.status == doing">Doing</span>
    <span ng-hide="task.status == done">Done</span>
</li>
```

or

```
<li ng-repeat="task in tasks">
  <div ng-switch on="task.status" >
    <span ng-switch-when="todo">Todo</div>
    <span ng-switch-when="doing">Doing</div>
    <span ng-switch-when="done">Done</div>
  </div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you. Wouldn't have thought it'd be that easy :)

Comment: Thanks @Florian F I had written a custom directive display-if.

I changed it now to use ng-hide, however it was worth to learn.

Comment: You should check ui-if from angular-ui